# Resolve generic type of method passed via delegate

Tags: c#, generics, .net-core, delegates

In my code, I am trying to dynamically resolve which type parameter should be used for a generic method call.

```
    private int FooResolver<T1, T2>(bool condition, Func<int> fooMethod)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            return fooMethod<T1>();
        }

        return fooMethod<T2>();
    }
```

I have created a wrapper method that takes in both type parameters and decides which one to use based on a condition... However, it seems C# does not allow this behavior. Are there any particular reasons for that? And is there a viable workaround for my code?

**EDIT**

After seeing the responses, I have decided to defer the type definition to the caller of the handler method:

```
private int FooResolver(bool condition, Func<int> foo1, Func<int> foo2)
{
    if (condition)
    {
        return foo1();
    }

    return foo2();
}

...

private int Bar()
{
    return FooResolver(myCondition, MyMethod<FirstType>, MyMethod<SecondType>);
}
```

Comment: You're `fooMethod` does not take any generic parameters, but you're trying to pass some to it.

Comment: 1) You're passing in a `Func<int>`. This takes an `int` and nothing else. 2) Your method returns an int. It can't return anything else.

Comment: @canton7 `Func<int>` doesn't take an `int` it returns one.

Comment: @Sean, please, can you explain how do I mark `fooMethod` to accept generic parameters? I couldn't find any answer to that... based on the C# semantics, it should be something like Foo<int><T> fooMethod... but this is labeled as invalid syntax.

Comment: This is not possible. A workaround would be to pass a generic `MethodInfo`, and call `MakeGenericMethod`... which is not nice :-(

Comment: @MarcGravell Badly worded -- I meant its single generic type parameter is filled by `int`

Comment: @canton7 But then point 2 doesn't stand, as the provided `Func` will return an `int`.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay It's hard to tell what the intention is, but one interpretation is that OP wants to return different things based on `condition` (since they're calling a `Func<T>` with different types of `T`, which means `fooMethod` returns different types, which they then try and return from `FooResolver`). My point 2 is that their `FooResolver` can only return `int`, not `T1` / `T2`

Comment: @canton7 My interpretation is they are trying to pass int-returning generic methods, but agreed, the intention isn't clear.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay, yes you are right, I was trying to pass int-returning generic method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delegates aren't abstractions to open generic methods or method-groups; they are an indirection to a *specific* closed method - i.e. everything is already resolved. You can *invoke* it, and you can use reflection to find out what it is pointing at, but *that's all* (caveat: for simplicity I'm talking about delegates in the unicast sense; they are technically multicast, but that detail probably doesn't matter here).

If you want to get hold of a *different* method in the method-group (things that share the same name), or a *different* generic parameter usage of the same generic method: you'll need to use reflection to get hold of that. You can't do it *directly* from the delegate instance.

If you demonstrate the intended usage here, we may be able to offer more guidance on ways to achieve what you are after, but: it probably won't be as simple or direct as you are hoping.